# How to Create Single.php for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post

I designed a template for WordPress, I've only encountered a problem in one section.
How can I create a post to display `single.php` for my site?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when saying "Post Display"?

Comment: Hi @morteza Ahmadi
Are you using default post type or custom post post type..

Comment: @AdirRatzon that page show posts contents in single page .

Comment: @YogeshGarg Default post type .. i want to show 1 post contents in single page .

Comment: @MortezaAhmadi every theme has single.php file by default. You can use that file. Even WordPress will automatically use single.php file of current theme. you can make changes in that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is a trivial thing. In order to show your *blog/websit*e posts, you need to call `the_post()` function inside of a loop.

As long there are posts in your blog, `the_post()` should render a response. Take a look at *Twenty_Fourteen* [single.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/single.php) default template in order to get a better understanding of how things should be.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a back up copy of **single.php**, call this `single-original.php`.
2. Open **single.php** file. Delete the contents of single.php and place the below code in it.

   ```
   <?php
    $post = $wp_query->post;
    if ( in_category('2') ) {
     include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single_new.php');
   } else {
      include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single_new1.php');
     }
   ?>
   ```
3. Open **single-original.php** and choose **File > Save As** and call this file **single_new.php**. Choose **File > Save As** again and call this file **single_new1.php**.
4. Upload **single.php**, **single_new.php** and **single_new1.php** as well as **style.css**, if you made changes in this.
5. Refresh your web page and click on one of the post titles in the category for which you are using **single_new1.php**.